# Rings as internal objects?

Tags: category-theory

Why rings can be seen as monoid objects internal to the category of abelian groups?

In the traditional way rings are abelian groups, but I do not understand the role of monoids! I know what internal means, but why monoids?

Comment: The category of abelian groups is a monoidal category under the tensor product with identity object $\Bbb Z$. If you write down what it means to have a monoid in such monoidal category, you should obtain the axioms that define a ring.

Answer (score 1):

The monoid structure encodes the ring multiplication, and the ring's $1$.

A [monoid object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category) in the category of abelian groups is a group $R$ equipped with a multiplication $\mu : R \otimes R \to R$ and a unit map $u: \mathbb{Z} \to R$ satisfying the associative and left and right unit laws. Since we are in the category of abelian groups, $\mu$ and $u$ are group homomorphisms. Notice that the conditions given are precisely those satisfied by rings.